# 'ng serve --environment=integration', seems not working in angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to create one more environment in angular2 named 'integration' and as part of my understanding on handling different environments, I created one more typescript file under environments folder as environment.integration.ts. And ran below command:

```
ng serve --environment=integration
```

But still environment.ts file is getting called which is for development environment.
My requirement is if someone runs ng serve with environment=integration, then integration host should be used which is specified in config.integration.ts.
Please let me know where I misunderstood the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `integration` entry to the .angular.cli.json config:

```
"environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
    "integration": "environments/environment.integration.ts"
}
```

Comment: sorry I missed it, but this entry I made in angular.cli.json file.